# Which tiles would make the most 7 letter words? (0-2 blanks)

Tags: anagram, scrabble

I just had "STRUNE?" (?=blank) and noticed A LOT of possible 7 letter words! Used an anagrammer and found 34! What is the combination of tiles is able to create the most 7 letter words?

- with no blanks
- with 1 blank
- with 2 blanks

Answer (score 8):

These are *[bingo stems](https://scrabble.merriam.com/bingo-stems)*, and the lifeblood of every salt-worthy scrabbler.

---

For no blanks:

> AEINRST, which has *anestri, antsier, nastier, ratines, retains, retinas, retsina, stainer,* and *stearin*

For one blank:

> AEINST? and AEIRST?, which both have 73 possible words.

For two blanks:

> I believe it's AERST??, which has [321 possible words](https://www.litscape.com/word_tools/contains_only_wc2.php)

Comment: Your first link first tries to load the page you actually mean but then autodirects just to https://playscrabble.com/

Comment: @quarague - that's peculiar; it works fine for me. Do you want to edit it?

Comment: I get the same thing. Presumably you have to be logged in to a Merriam account for it to load properly.